# Unificar registros iguales dentro de otro array

Tags: php

tengo un problema con un array, les platico lo que estoy intentando hacer. Tengo un array donde algunos registros tienen el mismo RFC, estoy intentando juntar los DIDS que tienen el mismo RFC y meterlos en otro array junto con los que no están repetidos, en pocas palabras estoy intentando unificar los DIDS de los registros que tienen el mismo RFC.

Les comparto el código que tengo hasta ahora y la funcionalidad.

> Array

```js
[0] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2763
    [RFC] => BPI190110BD2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Baker Parts International S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610024
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2761
    [RFC] => JIGD840519371
    [nombre_cuenta] => Diana IraÃ­ s Jimenez Galvan
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610026
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2843
    [RFC] => JMS090717EI8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Janome MÃ© xico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610041
        )
    )
[3] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2829
    [RFC] => HQM1801194P0
    [nombre_cuenta] => HA Quimica de Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610017
        [1] => 524421610078
        )
    )
[4] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2834
    [RFC] => KIN000203QL2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Kitagawa Northtech INC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610079
        )
    )
[5] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2814
    [RFC] => OSR090723DW7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Operadora de Servicios Rincon de la PeÃ± a SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[6] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2797
    [RFC] => CON0305305G8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Convamex SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610083
        [1] => 524422340387
        )
    )
[7] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2792
    [RFC] => CTM080924E54
    [nombre_cuenta] => Condominos Torre Medica Tec 100 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610085
        )
    )
[8] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2757
    [RFC] => VME1109302M3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Viter Medical SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610086
        )
    )
[9] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2788
    [RFC] => CWM020627SJ7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Cheong Woon Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610088
        )
    )
[10] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2937
    [RFC] => GCS980223AQ6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Global Computers Systems de Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610089
        [1] => 524426441979
        )
    )
[11] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2923
    [RFC] => MRE050908559
    [nombre_cuenta] => Majose Recicladora SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[12] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2778
    [RFC] => ACT940509777
    [nombre_cuenta] => Asociacion de Condominos TEC 100 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610398
        [1] => 524421610399
        )
    )
[13] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2818
    [RFC] => DFM0607108J9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Dos F Maquinaria SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610622
        )
    )
[14] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2830
    [RFC] => IKL900119HW3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Industrias kolaLoka SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610623
        [1] => 524421610628
        )
    )
[15] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2801
    [RFC] => DIC0510259G9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Desechos Industriales Conin SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610627
        )
    )
[16] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2769
    [RFC] => ASI150806I79
    [nombre_cuenta] => Agse Servicio Industrial Queretaro S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610629
        )
    )
[17] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2861
    [RFC] => WME180316B90
    [nombre_cuenta] => Weishaupt de Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610635
        [1] => 524421610643
        )
    )
[18] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2874
    [RFC] => RORG8912041H5
    [nombre_cuenta] => Guillermo Robles Ramirez
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610639
        )
    )
[19] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2822
    [RFC] => PES150424RA1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Promotora de Energia Y Suministros SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610641
        [1] => 524421615818
        [2] => 524421615819
        )
    )
[20] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2866
    [RFC] => ILP040422F37
    [nombre_cuenta] => Ilpea S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610800
        [1] => 524421610801
        [2] => 524421610802
        [3] => 524421610803
        [4] => 524421610804
        [5] => 524421610805
        [6] => 524421610806
        [7] => 524421610807
        [8] => 524421610808
        [9] => 524421610809
        [10] => 524421610810
        [11] => 524421610811
        [12] => 524421610812
        [13] => 524421610813
        [14] => 524421610814
        [15] => 524421610815
        [16] => 524421610816
        [17] => 524421610817
        [18] => 524421610818
        [19] => 524421610819
        [20] => 524421610820
        [21] => 524421610821
        [22] => 524421610822
        [23] => 524421610823
        [24] => 524421610824
        [25] => 524421610825
        [26] => 524421610826
        [27] => 524421610827
        [28] => 524421610828
        [29] => 524421610829
        [30] => 528110881406
        )
    )
[21] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2893
    [RFC] => TLE011122SC2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611002
        [1] => 525512090438
        [2] => 525512090439
        [3] => 525552024483
        )
    )
[22] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2836
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611010
        [1] => 524421611011
        [2] => 524421611012
        [3] => 524421611018
        )
    )
[23] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2756
    [RFC] => WME160926KBA
    [nombre_cuenta] => Weidner Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611015
        )
    )
[24] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2840
    [RFC] => FSE0506031Y6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Fine Servicios SC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 523310310430
        [1] => 524421611016
        [2] => 524421611017
        [3] => 524421612359
        [4] => 524421832500
        [5] => 525512090430
        )
    )
[25] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2750
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611019
        [1] => 524421611020
        [2] => 524421611212
        )
    )
[26] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2821
    [RFC] => PLQ9002286Q6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Productos Lacteos La Quinta, SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611211
        )
    )
[27] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2759
    [RFC] => EHW1111072A4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Easi Hw SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611214
        )
    )
[28] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2819
    [RFC] => GCI150525GR1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Grupo Caico IngenierÃ­ a y Servicios Comerciales SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611215
        )
    )
[29] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2800
    [RFC] => CPR170324E19
    [nombre_cuenta] => Ctcy Properties SAPI de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610042
        [1] => 524421611216
        [2] => 524421611220
        [3] => 524421613911
        )
    )
[30] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2816
    [RFC] => PAL011221575
    [nombre_cuenta] => Procesos Aledo S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611225
        [1] => 524421611226
        )
    )
[31] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2832
    [RFC] => OOCR931217QU5
    [nombre_cuenta] => Jose Roberto Osornio Chaparro
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611228
        )
    )
[32] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2795
    [RFC] => CON120606CX1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Construlandia SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[33] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2806
    [RFC] => HSA120507FJ6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Hidroponica El Sauz S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611230
        )
    )
[34] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2847
    [RFC] => MTM160107TN7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Mass Trading Mexicana SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611232
        )
    )
[35] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2760
    [RFC] => DME111122F34
    [nombre_cuenta] => Masterfoam Flexsolutions S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611233
        )
    )
[36] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2831
    [RFC] => IAG9210134B0
    [nombre_cuenta] => Internacional AgroIndustrial SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611234
        )
    )
[37] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2809
    [RFC] => MII110816AY3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Manejo Integral de Invernaderos SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611911
        )
    )
[38] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2783
    [RFC] => ACT141006RV1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Asociacion de Condominos Torre II Q7001 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612335
        [1] => 524421612336
        )
    )
[39] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2802
    [RFC] => DIN120208DY0
    [nombre_cuenta] => Dimaya Inmobiliaria SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612337
        )
    )
[40] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2803
    [RFC] => EGH03012742A
    [nombre_cuenta] => Edificaciones GH SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612338
        [1] => 524421614100
        )
    )
[41] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2768
    [RFC] => MUGA830904NZ2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Agni Jaim MuÃ± oz Granados
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612340
        )
    )
[42] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2780
    [RFC] => ACT141008J66
    [nombre_cuenta] => Asociacion de Condominos Torre I Q7001 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612341
        [1] => 524421612342
        )
    )
[43] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2765
    [RFC] => ARE1309204U1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Advance Real Estate 1 S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612346
        )
    )
[44] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2794
    [RFC] => CME1207027P0
    [nombre_cuenta] => Conexiones Mexicanas S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612350
        [1] => 524421612353
        )
    )
[45] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2855
    [RFC] => CTE090227BQ5
    [nombre_cuenta] => Cosechos de Tecozautla S.de PR de RL
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612351
        )
    )
[46] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2828
    [RFC] => TME160318KSA
    [nombre_cuenta] => TGK Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612352
        [1] => 524426441916
        [2] => 524426441917
        [3] => 524426441918
        )
    )
[47] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2953
    [RFC] => BOM0703205H2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Automotive Carrier and Protection Systems Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612358
        [1] => 524426441901
        [2] => 524426441903
        [3] => 524426441904
        [4] => 524426441905
        [5] => 524426441906
        [6] => 524426441907
        [7] => 524426441908
        [8] => 524426441909
        [9] => 524426441910
        )
    )
[48] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2862
    [RFC] => ZGU980116ND9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Zepeda Guerra SC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612590
        [1] => 524421612591
        [2] => 524422155015
        [3] => 524422168375
        )
    )
[49] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2889
    [RFC] => EXE050427KB6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Sames Kremlin SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612595
        )
    )
[50] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2767
    [RFC] => ARE1309205A7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Advance Real Estate 4 S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612596
        )
    )
[51] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2894
    [RFC] => ZIM9408055K6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Zimmer SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612598
        [1] => 524421614089
        [2] => 524421614090
        )
    )
[52] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2868
    [RFC] => GRS061012MQ4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Gruas y Refacciones San Juan SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524272641444
        [1] => 524272643444
        [2] => 524421612599
        )
    )
[53] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2751
    [RFC] => ARE1309204X6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Advance Real Estate 2 S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612602
        )
    )
[54] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2846
    [RFC] => MME720117483
    [nombre_cuenta] => Marubeni Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612603
        [1] => 524421612604
        )
    )
[55] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2804
    [RFC] => EGH03012742A
    [nombre_cuenta] => Edificaciones GH SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612345
        [1] => 524421612605
        )
    )
[56] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2920
    [RFC] => SME180214HFA
    [nombre_cuenta] => Streit Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612606
        [1] => 524421612609
        )
    )
[57] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2877
    [RFC] => COL131014R34
    [nombre_cuenta] => Colep SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612850
        [1] => 524421612855
        )
    )
[58] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2762
    [RFC] => BED030603KQ6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Bedemex SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612859
        )
    )
[59] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2841
    [RFC] => GIS030902L69
    [nombre_cuenta] => Grupo ISIMA SC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612860
        [1] => 524421820660
        [2] => 524421820661
        )
    )
[60] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2854
    [RFC] => TPH1808204B1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Typler PHE SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612866
        )
    )
[61] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2864
    [RFC] => TSU750725AS5
    [nombre_cuenta] => Transportes SUVI SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610071
        [1] => 524421610072
        [2] => 524421610073
        [3] => 524421610074
        [4] => 524421610075
        [5] => 524421610076
        [6] => 524421612867
        [7] => 524421612868
        [8] => 524421612869
        [9] => 525512091100
        )
    )
[62] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2865
    [RFC] => MED0102126I6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Mediapro SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610080
        [1] => 524421610084
        [2] => 524421610087
        [3] => 524421610091
        [4] => 524421610630
        [5] => 524421610631
        [6] => 524421610633
        [7] => 524421610634
        [8] => 524421610636
        [9] => 524421610637
        [10] => 524421610640
        [11] => 524421610644
        [12] => 524421611005
        [13] => 524421611021
        [14] => 524421611210
        [15] => 524421611219
        [16] => 524421611221
        [17] => 524421611222
        [18] => 524421611223
        [19] => 524421611224
        [20] => 524421612339
        [21] => 524421612343
        [22] => 524421612344
        [23] => 524421612356
        [24] => 524421612593
        [25] => 524421612594
        [26] => 524421612853
        [27] => 524421612854
        [28] => 524421612861
        [29] => 524421612862
        [30] => 524421613270
        [31] => 524421613271
        [32] => 524421613274
        [33] => 524421613275
        [34] => 524421613276
        [35] => 524421613277
        [36] => 524421613278
        [37] => 524421613279
        [38] => 524421614093
        [39] => 524421614095
        [40] => 524421614097
        [41] => 524421615802
        [42] => 524421615882
        [43] => 524421615884
        )
    )
[63] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2766
    [RFC] => ARE1309204X6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Advance Real Estate 2 S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421613281
        )
    )
[64] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2808
    [RFC] => LIN110310ET6
    [nombre_cuenta] => LOG Industrial SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421613285
        )
    )
[65] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2867
    [RFC] => TCB120502947
    [nombre_cuenta] => Tec 100 del Bajio SAPI de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421613287
        [1] => 524421613288
        [2] => 524421613289
        [3] => 525512090437
        )
    )
[66] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2825
    [RFC] => AME131202SW3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Royal Brinkman Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421614094
        [1] => 524421614096
        )
    )
[67] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2791
    [RFC] => CTM131017N54
    [nombre_cuenta] => Condominos TM II AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421614099
        )
    )
[68] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2815
    [RFC] => PLO9706125X8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Penske Logistica SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421614101
        [1] => 524421614102
        )
    )
[69] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2789
    [RFC] => CDT0907234H4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Comercializadora y Distribuidora El Temporal SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[70] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2869
    [RFC] => CDQ110523QF3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Cleveland Die Queretaro SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 523310310440
        [1] => 524421614110
        [2] => 524421614111
        [3] => 524421614112
        [4] => 524421614113
        [5] => 524421614114
        [6] => 524421614115
        [7] => 524421614116
        [8] => 524421614117
        [9] => 524421614118
        [10] => 524421614119
        [11] => 524421614120
        [12] => 524421614121
        [13] => 524421614122
        [14] => 524421614123
        [15] => 524421614124
        [16] => 524421614125
        [17] => 524421614126
        [18] => 524421614127
        [19] => 524421614128
        [20] => 524421614129
        [21] => 524421614130
        [22] => 524421614131
        [23] => 524421614132
        [24] => 524421614133
        [25] => 524421614134
        [26] => 524421614135
        [27] => 524421614136
        [28] => 524421614137
        [29] => 524421614138
        [30] => 524421614139
        [31] => 524491300430
        [32] => 525512090440
        [33] => 528111070943
        )
    )
[71] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2758
    [RFC] => JUA120130IU8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Juamai AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421614140
        )
    )
[72] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2799
    [RFC] => ACO000519AD1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abastecedora de Conectividad SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615050
        )
    )
[73] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2810
    [RFC] => CAMN770930LR1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Nashieli Cano Martinez
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615800
        )
    )
[74] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2826
    [RFC] => STM160706TJ9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Select Tool De Mexico S.De RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615801
        )
    )
[75] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2858
    [RFC] => VMA021210V85
    [nombre_cuenta] => Vafer Materiales SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[76] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2764
    [RFC] => AIN010316IL8
    [nombre_cuenta] => AMN International SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615806
        )
    )
[77] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2852
    [RFC] => PCO020902G83
    [nombre_cuenta] => Plasticos y Compuestos SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615808
        )
    )
[78] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2848
    [RFC] => NIA170830ST1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Novam Inovacion en Alimentos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615809
        )
    )
[79] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2817
    [RFC] => MEX110405SL1
    [nombre_cuenta] => 2948 - 4292 MEX SA DE CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615810
        [1] => 524421615811
        [2] => 524421615812
        [3] => 524421615813
        [4] => 524421615814
        [5] => 524421615815
        [6] => 524421615816
        )
    )
[80] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2853
    [RFC] => IDI990810MC4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Terminal Logistics Distribucion SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615821
        [1] => 524421615822
        )
    )
[81] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2860
    [RFC] => VVL180830Q9A
    [nombre_cuenta] => Vortex Valves Latinoamerica SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615823
        [1] => 524421615824
        )
    )
[82] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2857
    [RFC] => TSM1211292W4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Toolplas Systems Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615825
        [1] => 524421615826
        )
    )
[83] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2793
    [RFC] => CEQ1406121N0
    [nombre_cuenta] => Congeladora y Empacadora de Queretaro S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615883
        )
    )
[84] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2813
    [RFC] => OTC131125BL4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Omega Tool Canada de Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615885
        [1] => 524421615886
        [2] => 524421615887
        )
    )
[85] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2755
    [RFC] => WMA130513FJ4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Winners Mark SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421615889
        )
    )
[86] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2823
    [RFC] => RTO100818KU4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Radiologia Total SAPI de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421667101
        [1] => 524421667102
        )
    )
[87] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2883
    [RFC] => PRO930830UY1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Prodar SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421612608
        [1] => 524421935490
        [2] => 525512090433
        )
    )
[88] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2827
    [RFC] => SII090714CG9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Servicios de Informacion Integral SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524422135278
        [1] => 524422903062
        )
    )
```

Vi un ejemplo de algo que me podría ayudar, pero lo único que hace esa función es sacarme los registros que están duplicados.

> Mando llamar a la función

```
unique_multidim_array($array_cuentas, "RFC");
```

> Función

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    echo("entra al buscador");
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    print_r($temp_array);
}
```

> Ejemplo:

```
[22] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2836
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611010
        [1] => 524421611011
        [2] => 524421611012
        [3] => 524421611018
        )
    )
[25] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2750
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611019
        [1] => 524421611020
        [2] => 524421611212
        )
    )
```

Estos son registros duplicados porque el RFC es el mismo y necesito unificar los registros duplicados en un nuevo array, ejemplo:

```js
[25] => Array (
        [RFC] => ASE081010612
        [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
        [DIDS] => Array (
            [0] => 524421611010
            [1] => 524421611011
            [2] => 524421611012
            [3] => 524421611018
            [4] => 524421611019
            [5] => 524421611020
            [6] => 524421611212
            )
        )
```

No me importa la Troncal pero si el nombre de la cuenta y los DIDS unificados (juntos).

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Excelente lunes.

Comment: Y cuál es el error con lo que llevas? o qué no funciona?

Comment: la función que encontré si jala ya que me saca los datos duplicados del array, pero no necesito que los saque, mas bien necesito unificar los DIDS de los registros que tengan el mismo RFC y meterlos en otro array, en pocas palabra separarlos del resto y unificar sus DIDS de los registros con el RFC igual.

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo de como esperas que sea el resultado? creo que no logro captarlo

Comment: Listo, ya agregue un ejemplo.