# Iterar array para obtener únicamente los RFC y DIDS de los clientes

Tags: php

Hola buenos días compañeros, una pregunta.

¿Cómo itero el siguiente array para obtener e imprimir únicamente los datos de RFC y DIDS?

> Array

```
[0] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2763
    [RFC] => BPI190110BD2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Baker Parts International S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610024
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2761
    [RFC] => JIGD840519371
    [nombre_cuenta] => Diana IraÃ­ s Jimenez Galvan
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610026
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2843
    [RFC] => JMS090717EI8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Janome MÃ© xico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610041
        )
    )
[3] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2829
    [RFC] => HQM1801194P0
    [nombre_cuenta] => HA Quimica de Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610017
        [1] => 524421610078
        )
    )
[4] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2834
    [RFC] => KIN000203QL2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Kitagawa Northtech INC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610079
        )
    )
[5] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2814
    [RFC] => OSR090723DW7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Operadora de Servicios Rincon de la PeÃ± a SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[6] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2797
    [RFC] => CON0305305G8
    [nombre_cuenta] => Convamex SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610083
        [1] => 524422340387
        )
    )
[7] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2792
    [RFC] => CTM080924E54
    [nombre_cuenta] => Condominos Torre Medica Tec 100 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610085
        )
    )
[8] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2757
    [RFC] => VME1109302M3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Viter Medical SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610086
        )
    )
[9] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2788
    [RFC] => CWM020627SJ7
    [nombre_cuenta] => Cheong Woon Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610088
        )
    )
[10] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2937
    [RFC] => GCS980223AQ6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Global Computers Systems de Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610089
        [1] => 524426441979
        )
    )
[11] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2923
    [RFC] => MRE050908559
    [nombre_cuenta] => Majose Recicladora SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array()
    )
[12] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2778
    [RFC] => ACT940509777
    [nombre_cuenta] => Asociacion de Condominos TEC 100 AC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610398
        [1] => 524421610399
        )
    )
[13] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2818
    [RFC] => DFM0607108J9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Dos F Maquinaria SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610622
        )
    )
[14] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2830
    [RFC] => IKL900119HW3
    [nombre_cuenta] => Industrias kolaLoka SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610623
        [1] => 524421610628
        )
    )
[15] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2801
    [RFC] => DIC0510259G9
    [nombre_cuenta] => Desechos Industriales Conin SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610627
        )
    )
[16] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2769
    [RFC] => ASI150806I79
    [nombre_cuenta] => Agse Servicio Industrial Queretaro S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610629
        )
    )
[17] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2861
    [RFC] => WME180316B90
    [nombre_cuenta] => Weishaupt de Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610635
        [1] => 524421610643
        )
    )
[18] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2874
    [RFC] => RORG8912041H5
    [nombre_cuenta] => Guillermo Robles Ramirez
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610639
        )
    )
[19] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2822
    [RFC] => PES150424RA1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Promotora de Energia Y Suministros SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610641
        [1] => 524421615818
        [2] => 524421615819
        )
    )
[20] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2866
    [RFC] => ILP040422F37
    [nombre_cuenta] => Ilpea S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610800
        [1] => 524421610801
        [2] => 524421610802
        [3] => 524421610803
        [4] => 524421610804
        [5] => 524421610805
        [6] => 524421610806
        [7] => 524421610807
        [8] => 524421610808
        [9] => 524421610809
        [10] => 524421610810
        [11] => 524421610811
        [12] => 524421610812
        [13] => 524421610813
        [14] => 524421610814
        [15] => 524421610815
        [16] => 524421610816
        [17] => 524421610817
        [18] => 524421610818
        [19] => 524421610819
        [20] => 524421610820
        [21] => 524421610821
        [22] => 524421610822
        [23] => 524421610823
        [24] => 524421610824
        [25] => 524421610825
        [26] => 524421610826
        [27] => 524421610827
        [28] => 524421610828
        [29] => 524421610829
        [30] => 528110881406
        )
    )
[21] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2893
    [RFC] => TLE011122SC2
    [nombre_cuenta] => Tralix Mexico S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611002
        [1] => 525512090438
        [2] => 525512090439
        [3] => 525552024483
        )
    )
[22] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2836
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611010
        [1] => 524421611011
        [2] => 524421611012
        [3] => 524421611018
        )
    )
[23] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2756
    [RFC] => WME160926KBA
    [nombre_cuenta] => Weidner Mexico SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611015
        )
    )
[24] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2840
    [RFC] => FSE0506031Y6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Fine Servicios SC
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 523310310430
        [1] => 524421611016
        [2] => 524421611017
        [3] => 524421612359
        [4] => 524421832500
        [5] => 525512090430
        )
    )
[25] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2750
    [RFC] => ASE081010612
    [nombre_cuenta] => Abalon Servicios Electronicos S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611019
        [1] => 524421611020
        [2] => 524421611212
        )
    )
[26] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2821
    [RFC] => PLQ9002286Q6
    [nombre_cuenta] => Productos Lacteos La Quinta, SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611211
        )
    )
[27] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2759
    [RFC] => EHW1111072A4
    [nombre_cuenta] => Easi Hw SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611214
        )
    )
[28] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2819
    [RFC] => GCI150525GR1
    [nombre_cuenta] => Grupo Caico IngenierÃ­ a y Servicios Comerciales SA de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611215
        )
    )
[29] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2800
    [RFC] => CPR170324E19
    [nombre_cuenta] => Ctcy Properties SAPI de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421610042
        [1] => 524421611216
        [2] => 524421611220
        [3] => 524421613911
        )
    )
[30] => Array (
    [troncal] => 2816
    [RFC] => PAL011221575
    [nombre_cuenta] => Procesos Aledo S de RL de CV
    [DIDS] => Array (
        [0] => 524421611225
        [1] => 524421611226
        )
    )
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar lo que has intentado y un ejemplo del resultado que esperas.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Unificar registros iguales dentro de otro array](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/359102/unificar-registros-iguales-dentro-de-otro-array)

Comment: Estoy adaptando lo que obtuve de esta pregunta para poder resolver esta "Unificar registros iguales dentro de otro array"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una posible solución sería usar [array_filter()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php) y [in_array
()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php):

<kbd>**[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ba2371e3694b2d227a4ac1c88f6ab41c66de0b93)**</kbd>

```
<?php

$array =[

    0 => [
            'RFC' => 'RFC11 RFC11 RFC11 RFC11 RFC11',  
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'DIDS' => ['DIDS11', 'DIDS11']
               ],
    1 => [
            'RFC' => 'RFC22 RFC22 RFC22 RFC22 RFC22',  
            'foo' => 'bar',
            'DIDS' => ['DIDS22', 'DIDS22']
         ],                

];


foreach($array as $kn => $ks ) {

    $res[] = array_filter($ks, function ($k) {

        return in_array($k, ['RFC', 'DIDS']); // Aquí se establece el filtro deseado

    },  ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}  

var_dump($res);
```

Resultado:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["RFC"]=>
    string(29) "RFC11 RFC11 RFC11 RFC11 RFC11"
    ["DIDS"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "DIDS11"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "DIDS11"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["RFC"]=>
    string(29) "RFC22 RFC22 RFC22 RFC22 RFC22"
    ["DIDS"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "DIDS22"
      [1]=>
      string(6) "DIDS22"
    }
  }
}
```